Why FormView wont save the object while CreateView does?
I am still new in django, i searched in FormView and CreateView source code and i found they both inheritate form same things
this is my simple view which has inherited from FormView
class MyFormView(FormView):
    form_class = MyForm
    template_name = 'form.html'
    success_url = "/thanks/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)


i overwrote the form_valid method to try save my object
but in my CreateView
class PersonCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Person
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'form.html'


it saves my object automatically

Can you also post your form code please? is it a ModelForm?

Yes MyForm here is a ModelForm @RHSmith159

Pass, but it's easy to peruse the source code looking for the difference! Classy class-based views https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.2/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/

when you save your form is it definitely valid? does it ever actually reach form.save() in MyFormView?

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.
